# Cardinal number of eventually constant rational sequences

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $D_n=\{\langle d_k\rangle\in \mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}: (\exists q\in \mathbb{Q})(\forall k\geq n) \,d_k=q\}$, what is the cardinal number of $D_n$?

Is it $|D_n|=|\mathbb{Q}^\mathbb{N}|=|\mathbb{Q}|^{|\mathbb{N}|}=\aleph_0^{\aleph _0}=\aleph _0$?

Comment: I suppose $Q$ is the rationals.  Also $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0} \ne \aleph_0$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: there is a bijection between $D_n$ and $\mathbb{Q}^{n+1}$.

Edit: if you don't agree with me that zero is a natural number, then you will find it easier to construct a bijection between $D_n$ and $\mathbb{Q}^n$.

Comment: why ${Q}^{n+1}$?

Comment: The first $n + 1$ many rationals can be anything, and $d_n$ determines all the rest.  (Note that the natural numbers start at zero, not one.)

Comment: @user23709 By the way, I should echo GEdgar's comment that your last step is also mistaken.

Comment: Yes, I realized mistake... $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ is continuum.

Comment: For a more concrete hint, note that $(7,12,9) \in \mathbb{Q}_3$ corresponds to $(7,12,9,9,9,\ldots) \in D_2$.

Comment: @TrevorWilson Your claim about the natural numbers is a matter of convention: many people disagree with you!

Comment: @PeterTamaroff , do you mean it about he wrote that natural numbers starts from zero?

Comment: Yes @user23709 ${}{}{}$

Comment: @Peter: People who disagree with that convention are wrong... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equivalence relation on $D_n$, $\langle d_k\rangle\equiv\langle d'_k\rangle$ if and only if $d_k=d'_k$ for all $k<n$. This means that if they differ then it's only by the constant end segment of the sequence.

It is not very hard to show $\equiv$ is indeed an equivalence relation on $D_n$. Note that we can also choose from each equivalence class the unique representatives whose constant end segment is all $0$.

This means that there are $|\Bbb Q^n|=|\Bbb Q|^n=\aleph_0^n=\aleph_0$ equivalence classes. Each class contains exactly $|\Bbb Q|=\aleph_0$ different sequences (because each sequence is defined by the initial segment, and the rational from the end segment, and the initial segment is shared by all the sequences, and there are only $\aleph_0$ rational numbers).

Therefore $|D_n|=\aleph_0\cdot\aleph_0=\ldots$

Comment: This seems excessively complicated. Why treat the $n$-th coordinate differently from the preceding ones?

Comment: Trevor, of course it's excessively complicated! But you already gave out the simple solution... :-)

Comment: Well, if you are going for complexity I'm sure you can do even better than that.  Your answer didn't even use forcing :-)

Comment: Trevor, but it did use the axiom of choice! :-)